# protobuf-net serialization with inheritance does not work in some cases

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm currently struggeling with protobuf-net to have my classes correctly serialized.

I have the following class structure

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public bool IsOk { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ResultOfMyDtos : BaseClass<MyDto>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Validation { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm registering the subtypes like this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(BaseClass<MyDto>), true);
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ResultOfMyDtos), true);
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseClass<MyDto>)].AddSubType(1000, typeof(ResultOfMyDtos));
```

Now serializing the base class works fine, the List is correctly serialized:

```
// Works
var test1 = new BaseClass<MyDto>() { Results = new List<MyDto> { new MyDto { Name = "1" } } };
Serializer.Serialize(ms, test1)
```

Inheritance won't work at all, I just see the "IsOk" boolean:

```
// Does not return anything but the "IsOk" property
var test2 = new ResultOfMyDtos<MyDto>() { Validation = "Xy", Results = new List<MyDto> { new MyDto { Name = "1" } } };
  Serializer.Serialize(ms, test2)
```

Any ideas on this? Would be very nice, since I don't have a clue.

Comment: Write to file and look at the file :             StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, test1);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that worked for me:

1. You have to use ProtoInclude attribute from protobuf-net on your base class:

   ```
   [DataContract]
   [ProtoInclude(3, typeof(ResultOfMyDtos))]
   public class BaseClass<T>
   {
       // ... [cut] ...
   }
   ```
2. If it is not possible due to unavailability of the derived class at this point/library, OR this is not possible to use protobuf-net at this point/library of the base class (as i had, for example), you can redefine properties of your subclass:

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class ResultOfMyDtos : BaseClass<MyDto>
   {
       [DataMember(Order = 1)]
       public new bool IsOk
       {
           get { return base.IsOk; }
           set { base.IsOk = value; }
       }

       [DataMember(Order = 2)]
       public new List<MyDto> Results
       {
           get { return base.Results; }
           set { base.Results = value; }
       }

       [DataMember(Order = 3)]
       public string Validation { get; set; }
   }
   ```